# CakePHP 3: How to get current language value in views?

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

From CakePHP 3 Book

```
// Before (CakePHP 2)
Configure::write('Config.language', 'fr_FR');

// Now
I18n::locale('en_US');
```

Before in our CakePHP 2 app

```
<?php if(Configure::read('Config.language') != 'hrv') {  ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->Html->url('/hrv'); ?>" class="flag flag-hr">
        <?php echo __('Hrv', true); ?>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

How now in CakePHP 3?

in bootstrap:

```
ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'hr_HR');
```

in View?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quote from the `I18n::getLocale()` docs:

> [...]
>   Will return the currently configure locale as stored in the 
>   intl.default_locale PHP setting.
>   [...]

**https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.I18n.I18n.html#_getLocale**

So

```
use Cake\I18n\I18n;

if (I18n::getLocale() !== 'hr_HR') // ...
```